# How to deploy Single-Spa React app to PCF

Tags: reactjs, pcf, single-spa

Anyone know how to deploy React app that created using Single-Spa to PCF?

If I run `npm run build` in create-react-app it will create a "build" folder and I only need to push it with `cf push`.

But it will be "dist" folder for single spa. and it's not working after I pushed it.

Answer (score 0):

To point which folder you want to deploy, you need to set the *path* variable. It can be done either by the *manifest.yaml* file:

```
applications:
  - name: my-app
    path: build/
    buildpack: staticfile_buildpack
```

Or command line:

```
cf push my-app -b staticfile_buildpack -p build/
```

Reference: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html